# Add terms and condition to the new account registration

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can i add the checkbox and Content of the terms and condition when a user create new account.

The file we are talking about is register.phtml

Answer (score 5):

```
<li class="control">
         <div class="input-box">
           <input type="checkbox" id="privacy_policy" name="privacy_policy" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Accept the privacy policy') ?>" class="checkbox required-entry">
         </div>
        <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Accept the privacy policy') ?> (<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl( 6 ) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('privacy policy'); ?></a>)</label>
    </li>
```

This works great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My solution for register page:

```
   <li class="control">
         <div class="input-box">
           <input type="checkbox" id="privacy_policy" name="privacy_policy" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Accept the privacy policy') ?>" class="checkbox required-entry">
         </div>
        <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Accept the privacy policy') ?> (<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl( 6 ) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('privacy policy'); ?></a>)</label>
    </li>
```

Comment: That displays the checkbox, but how can you force submiting the form only if user has checked the box?

Comment: @ktsixit with class "required-entry"

Answer (score 1):

I add this into the register.phtml and works ok.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something" name="something" value="1" title="something" class="checkbox required-entry">
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CMS page for Terms and conditions and then include this in register.phtml.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-new-block')->toHtml();
```